# Django Sessions getting dropped when redirected from another domain

Tags: django, oauth

When a user visits my domain, a sessionid is issued by django. When he tries to do Oauth with Facebook, he clicks a button on my site which redirects to Facebook.com. Facebook redirects back to my domain, but at this point, the user's session is lost and Django seems to be issuing a new session variable.

I want the dropped session to persist because I must associate the visitor to my site with his Facebook account, but when the session is dropped, the logged in user is logged out.

I have a suspicion that this may be behavior related to django's XSS protection. How do I make the user information persist when the user leaves our site to log in at Facebook?

Comment: Does your issue have anything to do with http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions ? Also, define the session is dropped. Does the 'user' still have its cookie?

Comment: The session is dropped means that the original session id cookie is erased and replaced with a new one. Thank you for the link, it seems to indicate that sessions should not be erased when the user visits a new site and returns to the original domain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to confirm that the cookies have the same domain when being created. That can sometimes cause problems. If you are going to the website www.example.com and the OAuth callback points to example.com, then it's possible you have two separate cookies, one for www.example.com and one for example.com

Turn on "Always Ask" on your browser and pay attention to the cookie details. Make sure that the value for the "Host:" field is the same both times.

The fix is entering something like `.example.com` for `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it looks like the problem is solved, thanks!

Comment: Been stuck on this for like 2 hours x_x.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: This was happening to me because I was starting out on `localhost` and then coming back on `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 4):

I've also just discovered that if you have two Django applications running on the same domain, to avoid cookie collision you may wish to set SESSION_COOKIE_NAME differently for each.