# Getting Django error 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable after redirecting back from Stripe page

Tags: django, stripe-connect

So it is my understanding that this error comes about from trying to call 
`request.user` when a user isn't logged in. The problem I'm having is, I am using [Stripe Connect Express](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference) so I can have users sign up with debit card or bank account for payouts in my marketplace app. This redirects the user to stripe for a few pages. When Stripe collects the data it needs it redirects the user back to my page where I use `request.user` to pull their info from the database so I can save Stripe data to their table.

I'd say about 50% of the time this is successful and the other half I get the error

`TypeError at /pricing/
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

This leads me to believe that the user is logged out sometime during the redirect to Stripe. Is there a solution to this issue? Is my session expired? Did the CSRF token change?

Also, Stripe allows you to pass a 'state' query parameter in the POST request to them which they suggest to is for matters like CSRF tokens. They then return this 'state' to you in the redirect GET request they send from their servers. Can I take this information to possibly fix my issue?

Comment: Think we would need a stacktrace to diagnose better. I might be crazy but usually request.user isn't going to be iterable either

Comment: Well I made some modifications and thought I fixed it but did not. Same issue but in different form. Basically when redirecting back from Stripe sometimes request.user works and other times it does not. This time I got the following error: 

Exception Type: AttributeError at /pricing/confirmed
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'

that is with trying to run request.user.email

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628614/django-sessions-getting-dropped-when-redirected-from-another-domain). I originally had my redirect uri listed on Stripe as 127.0.0.1...but I have been developing in localhost assuming it just abstracted the aforementioned - but apparently it may've been creating 2 different cookies. Been through a bunch of test cases so far and seems to have fixed it.

Comment: You are 100% absolutely right. I had the reverse problem - was using localhost when developing on 127.0.0.1. Thanks for sharing.