# Django - Stripe Integration . Redirect URI being converted from 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Tags: django, redirect, stripe-payments, django-authentication

Django 2.1
Python 3.7
Stripe - Connect / Express

I am using stripe and django to create a payment system. To set up the user account, I send the user to stripe and then have them redirected back to the website. I am currently developing this on my server 127.0.0.1. Whenever the user is redirected back, they are in a new session sees them as an `AnonymousUser`.

I've looked at some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356951/getting-django-error-anonymoususer-object-is-not-iterable-after-redirecting-ba) and they point out that this happens when 2 cookies are created. E.g. you start out at 127.0.0.1 and endup at localhost. I just solved this issue for me by starting on localhost and then ending on localhost. However, I can't seem to start on 127.0.0.1 and end up on 127.0.0.1

My redirect URI is `'redirect_uri': f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/billing/oauth/callback'` but I get redirected back to localhost which causes the two cookies.

Does anyone know why 127.0.0.1 is being converted to localhost and how I can get 127.0.0.1 back?

```
class StripeEntryView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'billing/stripe.html'
    model = BillingProfile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['stripe_user_id'] = billing_profile.stripe_user_id
        return context

class StripeAuthorizeView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
        url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize'
        params = {
            'redirect_uri': f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/billing/oauth/callback',
            'client_id': STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID,
            'stripe_user[email]':self.request.user.email,
            'requested_capabilities[]':'platform_payments',   
        }
        url = f'{url}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}'
        return redirect(url)
```